# Dialog XAML and Material Design WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design, material-design-in-xaml

I am trying to make a dialog popup on a xaml page within my WPF app. I am using [Material Design In XAML Toolkit](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML).

The page is within a frame on the main window. I want to make the darkened dialog background go all the way over a menu which in on the main window. (Picture Example: [Dialog background going over menu and full window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS6c5.png))

On my page with the button, I have the following code

```
<Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}" 
                            Width="128" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" >
        <Button.CommandParameter>
            <system:DateTime></system:DateTime>
        </Button.CommandParameter>
        Popup
    </Button>
```

Then on my main window, I have the following code:

```
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:DateTime}">
            <StackPanel Margin="16">
                <TextBlock>Example!!</TextBlock>
                <Button  Margin="0 8 0 0" IsDefault="True" Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignRaisedDarkButton}">Close</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

I've also included

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

When I run the app I have no errors and it opens, but the button named "Popup" is disabled. But this code does run and work in the [Material Design Demo](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/tree/master/MainDemo.Wpf) when I change it there.

I am new to XAML and this is my first app using this language, so the help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your MainWindow.xaml content should look like this

```
 <materialDesign:DialogHost Identifier="RootDialog">
     <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
        <!--dialog content-->
    </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
     <Grid>
       <!--your window cotnent-->
     </Grid>
 </materialDesign:DialogHost>
```